# R: generate dataframe of Friday dates for the year

Tags: r

I would like to generate a dataframe that contains all the Friday dates for the whole year.
Is there a simple way to do this?

eg for December 2013: (6/12/13,13/12/13,20/12/13,27/12/13)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure there is a simpler way, but you could brute force it easy enough:

```
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2013-01-01"),as.Date("2013-12-31"),by="1 day")

dates[weekdays(dates)=="Friday"]
dates[format(dates,"%w")==5]
```

Building on @Frank's good work, you can find all of any specific weekday between two dates like so:

```
pick.wkday <- function(selday,start,end) {
  fwd.7 <- start + 0:6
  first.day <- fwd.7[as.numeric(format(fwd.7,"%w"))==selday]
  seq.Date(first.day,end,by="week")
}
```

`start` and `end` need to be `Date` objects, and `selday` is the day of the week you want (0-6 representing Sunday-Saturday).

i.e. - for the current query:

```
pick.wkday(5,as.Date("2013-01-01"),as.Date("2013-12-31"))
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way.

```
d <- as.Date(1:365, origin = "2013-1-1")
d[strftime(d,"%A") == "Friday"]
```

Alternately, this would be a more efficient approach for generating the data for an arbitrary number of Fridays:

```
wk1 <- as.Date(seq(1:7), origin = "2013-1-1") # choose start date & make 7 consecutive days
wk1[weekdays(wk1) == "Friday"]                # find Friday in the sequence of 7 days

seq.Date(wk1[weekdays(wk1) == "Friday"], length.out=50, by=7) # use it to generate fridays
```

`by=7` says go to the next Friday.
`length.out` controls the number of Fridays to generate.  One could also use `to` to control how many Fridays are generated (e.g. use `to=as.Date("2013-12-31")` instead of `length.out`).

Comment: I've put your example as a function into my answer - works well for arbitrary start and end points.

Answer (score 3):

Takes a year as input and returns only the fridays...

```
getFridays <- function(year) {      
  dates <- seq(as.Date(paste0(year,"-01-01")),as.Date(paste0(year,"-12-31")), by = "day")
  dates[weekdays(dates) == "Friday"]      
}
```

Example:

```
> getFridays(2000)
 [1] "2000-01-07" "2000-01-14" "2000-01-21" "2000-01-28" "2000-02-04" "2000-02-11" "2000-02-18" "2000-02-25" "2000-03-03" "2000-03-10" "2000-03-17" "2000-03-24" "2000-03-31"
[14] "2000-04-07" "2000-04-14" "2000-04-21" "2000-04-28" "2000-05-05" "2000-05-12" "2000-05-19" "2000-05-26" "2000-06-02" "2000-06-09" "2000-06-16" "2000-06-23" "2000-06-30"
[27] "2000-07-07" "2000-07-14" "2000-07-21" "2000-07-28" "2000-08-04" "2000-08-11" "2000-08-18" "2000-08-25" "2000-09-01" "2000-09-08" "2000-09-15" "2000-09-22" "2000-09-29"
[40] "2000-10-06" "2000-10-13" "2000-10-20" "2000-10-27" "2000-11-03" "2000-11-10" "2000-11-17" "2000-11-24" "2000-12-01" "2000-12-08" "2000-12-15" "2000-12-22" "2000-12-29"
```

Answer (score 2):

There are probably more elegant ways to do this, but here's one way to generate a vector of Fridays, given any year.

```
year = 2007
st <- as.POSIXlt(paste0(year, "/1/01"))
en <- as.Date(paste0(year, "/12/31"))

#get to the next Friday
skip_ahead <- 5 - st$wday
if(st$wday == 6) skip_ahead <- 6  #for Saturdays, skip 6 days ahead.

first.friday <- as.Date(st) + skip_ahead
dates <- seq(first.friday, to=en, by ="7 days")

dates
#[1] "2007-01-05" "2007-01-12" "2007-01-19" "2007-01-26"
# [5] "2007-02-02" "2007-02-09" "2007-02-16" "2007-02-23"
# [9] "2007-03-02" "2007-03-09" "2007-03-16" "2007-03-23"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be the most efficient way and would also returns all the Friday in the whole of 2013.

```
FirstWeek <-   seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), as.Date("2013/1/7"), "days")
seq(
  FirstWeek[weekdays(FirstWeek) == "Friday"],
  as.Date("2013/12/31"),
  by = "week"
)
```